# So, what's left to do? (GSC Performance Drops)

Tags: seo, google-search-console, google-search, search-engine-indexing

As a developer, I am quite new in SEO area. I published my website 40 days ago. Before to start this goal, I read and learn much about SEO. I am still learning but actually I can not find so much thing to do more. I researched for keyword curiously that I want to get rank and some of them have low difficulty.

- Semantic html with all necessary tags/attributes.
- SSL
- Speed (pagespeed score like 90)
- AMP (all paged completely valid even without any warning).
- Microdata
- New, unique and qualified content (once or twice a week)
- Most seo report sites (semrush, seobility, seositecheckup) gives me more than %90.
- No error or warning on GSC / Bing webmaster / Yandex webmaster
- Valid sitemap.xml, robots.txt
- Totally curious title and meta tags.
- Backlinks (I bought from some freelancers), I disavowed some of my spammy backlinks. Semrush gives the backlink quality %96.
- Valid redirects for http and non-www versions.
- Ahrefs gives PR 70+, DR 26+ (increasing)
- 100% uptime from first publish.
- Stellar hosting (closest servers), Cloudflare pro plan, no security issue.

These are my checklist and there are other things also I don't remember right now. I am pushing hard actually in my opinion but although I am expecting the rise, my gsc performance graph drops significantly.

[image: gsc]

What about my competitors ?

For my aimed keywords, most (really most) of them in first page (event the first one) has not the %70 of my checklist (even SSL) for SEO.

So, what is the point of Google? Why I could not get what I deserve instead of my competitors?

Comment: I wouldn't call that a drop.  Google was "tasting" your site.  It tried it out in better position that it would normally get just to see how it would do.   Google does that with most new content.   Now that Google's experiment is over, you don't get the bump of your honeymoon period in the search results.

Comment: You can't expect a 40 day old site to have good rankings for anything at all.  It takes a couple years to get there.   The biggest thing you need to do is give it time.  During that time, grow the reputation of your site.

Comment: Even if I did most of the things better than my competitors and try to improve all necessary things quickly, do I need to still wait for long time? It is not fair at all. @StephenOstermiller

Comment: The biggest factor in ranking is site reputation.   It takes time to build that.    Your competitors have a head start in this regard if they have already had sites online for years.  Google measures site reputation mostly through external links.  It is possible to expedite that process somewhat by building links.   However, it is a risky business and needs to be done with utmost care to avoid Google penalties for spamming.   See [Is link building a white hat SEO activity?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/18643/is-link-building-a-white-hat-seo-activity)

Comment: Currently, I am working with some freelancer to increase my backlinks. I can not find much without spend money for my quite new website as you can guess. I know that I did not trust all the domain they'll give backlink to mydomain. My plan is wait to finish all done and start to pick over the toxic ones. So, when I disavow the spammy links and keep the good ones, it is make sense for me? What do you think about it? @StephenOstermiller

Comment: Building any toxic links will hurt your site forever.   I would never build bad links planning to disavow them later.  If you are in a situation where you need to disavow links to your site, Google has already penalized you and at best you will be able to get back a fraction of the site reputation you had before you were penalized.

Comment: It is like a act that someone can do for attacking my site for seo. So, when I get good rank, a competitor might build many toxic links to my site. How google understand this action was an attack or I did it myself? Thus, it feels like this is what disavow tool is for. It should be give back my reputation if I disavow the domains I did not get backlinks from. Of course, I got your idea, I'll be careful much more about my backlinks. @StephenOstermiller

Comment: Attacking a site with spammy links is known as "negative SEO".   See [Is negative SEO fact or fiction](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/65011/is-negative-seo-fact-or-fiction).  A brutish attack will get all bad links and no good links, but that looks very different from a somebody buying links that they think will help them and Google can identify it as negative SEO.   An effective negative SEO includes good links as well so it looks like link building.   However, such an attack often helps the attacked site in the short term and most spammers don't usually have the patience.

Comment: Thanks for your all explanation @StephenOstermiller. It was really helpfull. As you can see, I need speed and I don't have that patience either. That is why, I am trying to do all things depends on my hands. Although that, it makes me upset to not see any good news from Google. I will try better and hope to see the big G will react fair to me.